# Function to perform calculations and paste result in dataframe in r (using loops and paste?)

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I am hoping this is an easy answer. I have a lot of gene expression data. I wish to perform calculations on this data (i.e. normalising to the housekeepers and calculating a fold change (delta Ct)). I have been doing this individually as follows, but I know there must be a paste function and loop that can do this easily.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Sample = c("Red", "Green", "Blue"),
                 Gene1 = rnorm(3, mean = 30, sd = 1),
                 Gene2 = rnorm(3, mean = 27, sd = 1),
                 Gene3 = rnorm(3, mean = 26, sd = 1),
                 Housekeeper = rnorm(3, mean = 25, sd = 1))

#Individually
#DCT = delta Ct, fc = fold change
df$dct_Gene1 <- df$Gene1 - df$Housekeeper
df$fc_Gene1 <- 2^-df$dct_Gene1
df

#repeat for gene2 etc
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Making 5 separate vectors and then renaming them all at the end is a very round-about way to make a data frame! I have simplified your example and added `set.seed` to make your `rnorm` reproducible. I also prefer _e.g._ `df1` to `df` since the latter is a function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape to long format is the way to go here. I don't think there's a need for `group_by`, at least using your example data, since each row will be a sample, its housekeeper value and a gene.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Sample, Housekeeper)) %>% 
  mutate(dct = value - Housekeeper, 
         fc = 2 ^ -dct)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 6
  Sample Housekeeper name  value     dct     fc
  <chr>        <dbl> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Red           24.6 Gene1  29.4  4.89   0.0338
2 Red           24.6 Gene2  27.1  2.52   0.175 
3 Red           24.6 Gene3  26.5  1.91   0.267 
4 Green         26.2 Gene1  29.8  3.55   0.0856
5 Green         26.2 Gene2  27.1  0.905  0.534 
6 Green         26.2 Gene3  24.7 -1.49   2.81  
7 Blue          25.4 Gene1  31.6  6.20   0.0136
8 Blue          25.4 Gene2  28.7  3.36   0.0977
9 Blue          25.4 Gene3  25.3 -0.0467 1.03
```

Comment: Beat me to it, so have a +1. The value of simplifying the 1/2/3 naming is pretty evident in how simple the code becomes.

Comment: Thanks! My data is originally in this format and I pivot_wider in preparation for graphing. I will just reorder my workflow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may not need wide data for graphing if you're using `ggplot`, which also works better using long format.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider working in long format, but to directly answer your question, you can use `dplyr`'s `mutate` and `across` and put the named functions in a list, and use those names to create new columns using the `.names` command:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Gene"),  
                list(fct = ~.x - Housekeeper, 
                     fc = ~2^.x), 
                .names = "{.fn}_{.col}"))

# or to specify with column number:

df %>%
  mutate(across(2:4,  
                list(fct = ~.x - Housekeeper, 
                     fc = ~2^.x), 
                .names = "{.fn}_{.col}"))
```

Output:

```
  Sample    Gene1    Gene2    Gene3 Housekeeper fct_Gene1   fc_Gene1 fct_Gene2  fc_Gene2  fct_Gene3 fc_Gene3
1    Red 30.55430 26.81337 26.52333    25.07480  5.479499 1576738920 1.7385745 117931400  1.4485339 96453618
2  Green 30.20740 27.80708 24.49762    24.66050  5.546905 1239748674 3.1465841 234836177 -0.1628774 23687424
3   Blue 31.11836 25.61790 25.32562    25.03689  6.081474 2331100701 0.5810144  51494128  0.2887267 42050421
```

Comment: Thanks! In my real data, the columns do not start with Gene, they are the actual gene name. Any ideas to get around this?

Comment: Great! @MM1 - see edit - you can specify columns a number of ways. Perhaps in your case specifying by column number is easiest and it will result in identical output. Good luck!

Comment: +1 for answering the question as posed. Speaking from hard-learnt mistakes, it is rather error-prone to rely on sets of variable prefixes which can later clash with other variables, or variable indexes that can change due to upstream processing differences. Structure the data properly to start with, and simplify the code from that point on. You conceptually have one variable - `Gene` and 3 repeated recordings of it - so have one column `Gene`, and another column `Time` or `Seq_number` to identify the repeats. Then all your code only needs to reference `Gene` without any looping or selection.

Comment: Those `fc` values look very high? In the original question the formula is `2 ^ -dct` not `2 ^ dct`.

Comment: It is because the 2^ is being applied to the original column, not the newly created dct column.